# Location for putting folders a play application

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I've a command line Java program that uses multiple folders containing files representing models, indices and resources that are loaded and used by some of the Java classes at runtime.

I'm trying to convert this program to a Play application (Scala) to provide a RESTFul interface. My question where should I put these folders so that they will be accessible by the Java classes when my Play application is running?

I'm using play-2.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

you can add folder to classpath via SBT ( check out [sbt document](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Classpaths.html) ),
so playframework can find you class, and then create some play action to reuse the service which you already have.

and, if you just want to wrap your application to provide some REST API, I'd like to recommend [Spray](http://spray.io/) to you, which can make your application export as REST API more easy. Hope this helps.